# Java Lucene Stop Words Filter

Tags: java, filter, lucene, words

I have about 500 sentences in which I would like to compile a set of ngrams. I am having trouble removing the stop words. I tried adding the lucene StandardFilter and StopFilter but I still have the same problem. Here is my code:

```
for(String curS: Sentences)
{
          reader = new StringReader(curS);
          tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);
          tokenizer = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenizer);
          tokenizer = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenizer, stopWords);
          tokenizer = new ShingleFilter(tokenizer, 2, 3);
          charTermAttribute = tokenizer.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    while(tokenizer.incrementToken())
    {
        curNGram = charTermAttribute.toString().toString();
        nGrams.add(curNGram);                   //store each token into an ArrayList
    }
}
```

For example, the first phrase I am testing is: "For every person that listens to". In this example curNGram is set to "For" which is a stop word in my list stopWords. Also, in this example "every" is a stop word and so "person" should be the first ngram.

1. Why are stop words being added to my list when I am using the StopFiler?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: How is stopWords being created?  Do you create it using [StopFilter.makeStopSet](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html#makeStopSet(org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20java.util.List,%20boolean))?

Comment: I read in a txt file line by line using a static function.

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted looks okay to me, so I suspect that stopWords isn't providing the information you want to the filter.

Try something like:

```
//Let's say we read the stop words into an array list (A simple array, or any list implementation should be fine)
List<String> words = new ArrayList();
//Read the file into words.
Set stopWords = StopFilter.makeStopSet(Version.LUCENE_36, words, true);
```

Assuming the list you of stopwords you generated (the one I've named 'words') looks like you think it does, this should put them into a format usable to the StopFilter.

Were you already generating stopWords like that?

Comment: This appears to be working however for some of my output I am getting the same words except one will have an extra underscore or two. For example I will get USA, USA_, USA__ all as distinct values.

Comment: That is intended behavior of ShingleFilter, from the API: "This filter handles position increments > 1 by inserting filler tokens (tokens with termtext "_"). It does not handle a position increment of 0."  This is due to words being removed by the stop filter, ShingleFilter maintains their position in that way.

Comment: If you wish, I believe you could disable that with stopfilter.setEnablePositionIncrements(false)