# N-grams from a Sentence [Lucene 4.9]

Tags: java, lucene, n-gram, sentence

I am trying to implement an example that is able to generate n grams from a sentence (same question asked here [N-gram generation from a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656762/n-gram-generation-from-a-sentence)) with the current latest version of Lucene (Lucene 4.9). 
I found several examples, but made ​​with previous versions of Lucene (one on all http://toolongdidntread.com/lucene/using-lucene-to-generate-n-grams/).

In all the examples, if you do not use the correct libraries (the correct version), I get an "abstract method error". 
Can someone help me to implement an example, using libraries of version 4.9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While there have been considerable changes to Lucene since the cited question, [ShingleFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) is still what you are looking for.  Can provide more details on the exact problem you are having and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I saw your response(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433670/java-lucene-ngramtokenizer) and i solved it. (I forgot to invoke the reset on the TokenStream) Thanks for the reply.